# Jira rest api search DNS error on Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to do a query on Jira and put these results on my google spreadsheet. Initially, I've tried to get the json file, but I've always have a DNS error on my response. When I get the link and insert it on the browser I am able to see the content on the screen.

I am supposed that it may be related to the authentication (Utilities.base64Encode(...)), but I don't know because the Google sheet only shows me:

> DNS error: https://host.com.br/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee%20=%20currentUser()%20AND%20resolution%20=%20Unresolved%20order%20by%20updated%20DESC

Does anyone know how to help me, please?

Thank you

```
function testJiraConnection()
{
  var baseURL = "https://host.com.br/rest/api/2/search";
  var username = "user";
  var password = "password";
  var encCred = Utilities.base64Encode(username+":"+password);

  var headers = { 
   "Accept":"application/json", 
   "Content-Type":"application/json", 
   "Authorization":"Basic "+ encCred
 };

  var options = { 
    "method":"POST",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "headers": headers,
 };
 var jql = "?jql=assignee = currentUser() AND resolution = Unresolved order by updated DESC";
 Logger.log(baseURL + jql);
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseURL + jql, options);
 Logger.log(response); 
}
```

Comment: Your base URL for Jira may not be right. It should be https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/search.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The url is wrong but it is not this one neither. I still don't know how to make the query by Google script. Just I know how to make it with _curl_. Do you know something related to it?

Comment: @MariaIsabel did you ever find the solution to this problem? Or did anyone else?

Comment: No solution. Actually I solved my problem with an alternative solution.

Comment: @MariaIsabel Mind sharing how you solved it?